# How to fit a line with fixed points? (in R)

Tags: r, regression

I have a few point pairs and I want to fit a line for them in R. I am now using loess but its prediction also changes the value of the original points. I want to find a fit that can generate a line with these fixed points, not necessarily polynomial fit.

This is my original code:

```
height = c(0, 11000, 20000, 32000, 47000, 51000, 71000, 84852)
beta = c(-0.0065, 0, 0.001, 0.0028, 0, -0.0028, -0.002, 0)

heightseq = seq(0, 84900, 100)
loesssmooth <- loess(beta ~ height, degree = 2)
pred = predict(loesssmooth, data.frame(height = heightseq), se = T)
plot(height, beta, col = "gray")
lines(heightseq, pred$fit, lwd = 2)
```

Comment: I tried an equation search on the raw data and on scaled data. A 3rd order polynomial was my best determination in both cases. While it does fit, the plot does not look to me as if it is the correct model for this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for interpolation.

```
## linear interpolation
linear <- approx(height, beta, xout = heightseq)
plot(linear, type = "l"); points(height, beta, col = 8)

## natural cubic spline interpolation
ncs <- spline(height, beta, xout = heightseq, method = "natural")
plot(ncs, type = "l"); points(height, beta, col = 8)
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I use "predict" function later? like: `predict(ncs, data.frame(height = 0))` This code doesn't work! Cause my ultimate goal is to use this line to predict a specific number.

Comment: @Dianafreedom Use the `xout` argument in `approx` or `spline` for prediction at new locations.